# How to get images of recently viewed products in sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, small-image

In my store `recently viewed products` name only displayed, i need to `visible images of recently viewed products.`

[image]

Comment: check my code and comment me whether it is working or not please confirm me jeeva. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have tried and got the solution add the below piece of code in the **product_viewed.phtml** in the specified path in between li tag

**/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml**

```
   <li class="item">
    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl($_item) ?>">
    <span class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50, 50)->setWatermarkSize('30x10'); ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" />
    </span>
    </a>
    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?></a></p>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml.

Modified to add images

```
<?php if ($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()): ?>
<div>
<div>
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Recently Viewed Products') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div>
<ol id="recently-viewed-items">
<?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
<li>
<p><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /> </p>
<p><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?></a></p>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateList('recently-viewed-items');</script>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That’s it, you should now have product thumbnails above your product name, if not refresh your cache and then see if it works

Comment: There is no "reports"  path in my root folder

Comment: I f you have fresh magento installed check via rwd theme.

Comment: How can i use in my manual template

Comment: I think you need to override product_viewed.phtml in your theme.

Comment: Am just replaced with your code, its not working,

Comment: path is : /public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/reports

Comment: screen shots :    http://i.imgur.com/vFWjBi7.png

Comment: Do not replace for rwd. These functionality is already there in rwd.These was for customized theme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44983/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-arjun).

Comment: Not working......

Comment: Try using the same code as rwd.